# Magento 2: How to translate the minicart?

Tags: magento2, overrides, inline-translations

I'm building an online store using Magento **version 2.1.8**. I've created a Luma child-theme.

Magento offers CSV files for translating most of it. But the *minicart* uses JavaScript for the text strings within it.

[image]

How can I **overwrite** the default English text, for Romanian?

Comment: If i recall correctly this should be also included in the CSV you mentioned, no matter if it is PHP or JS.

Comment: The Magento installation has many CSVs (every module has one).  Wich CSV are _you_ writing about?

Comment: I don't know which text are you trying to translate, but you can try something like this to search in the CSV files https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=language%3Acsv+cart&type=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For JS translate you must create language pack with below files.

**/app/i18n/Myshop/ro_ro/language.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>ro_RO</code>
    <vendor>Myshop</vendor>
    <package>ro_ro</package>
</language>
```

**/app/i18n/Myshop/ro_ro/registration.php**:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'myshop_ro_ro',
    __DIR__
);
```

**/app/i18n/Myshop/ro_ro/ro_RO.csv** with your translates (examples):

```
"Cart Subtotal:","Costul mărfurilor:"
"Go to Checkout","Du-te la checkout"
...
```

For apply your store must use Romanian locale, of course. JS translates are stored in **/pub/static/frontend/Myshop/Mytheme/ro_RO/js-translation.json**.

Remove this file for refresh, clear cache and browser local storage. Enjoy!

Comment: The file/directory structure is different from yours, in Magento 2

Comment: The `Vendor` directory is directly under `root`.

Comment: Vendor in paths in my answer is your vendor, replace it to your development's name. It's not vendor directory under root.

Comment: What is the right path in **Magento version 2.1.8**?

Comment: Ok, Razvan, what is directory of your custom theme? Tell me, please. In /app/design/frontend/..

Comment: app/design/frontend/Myshop/Mytheme

Comment: In here I have `/app/design/frontend/Myshop/Mytheme/i18n` with the `en_EN.csv` and `ro_RO.csv` files inside.

Comment: I updated my answer, all paths are corrected. Check it, please.

Comment: There is no `i18n` directly in the app directory. Shall I create one?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: But there already is one  `i18n` inside Mytheme...

Comment: i18n inside theme not work for JS translates. It's works in PHP only.

Comment: I did what you said. It does _not_ work.

Comment: Do you have necessary translates in js-translation.json? Is this file refreshed?

Comment: It can not be deleted (it is _read only_). I cleared the cache.

Comment: You need to update this file, otherwise translates will not work. If you delete file - it should be created automatically, when you first access to site.

Comment: The contents of this file is `[]`

Comment: After update? Do you have any suggestions in ro_RO.csv in language pack?

Comment: Yes. I have translations.

Comment: Your store using Romanian locale? Clear cache in Magento, clear browser local storage.. try again. It is work properly for me. Your translates must appear in js-translations.json.

Comment: Try also to run php bin/magento setup:upgrade and php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65962/discussion-between-razvan-zamfir-and-evgeny-levinsky).

Comment: In Linux? In what directory?

Comment: These are the paths:
 `/app/i18n/Myshop/ro_ro/language.xml`
 `/app/i18n/Myshop/ro_ro/registration.php`
 `/app/i18n/Myshop/ro_ro/ro_RO.csv'

Comment: Yes, all right. You need upgrade and deploy static, I wrote in chat.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works. Be warned that you should use exactly the same letter cases as the author.

Comment: what to you mean by MyShop??

Answer (score 0):

Hello Evgeny Levinsky I have similar issue with italian language.
But I'm not understanding where exactly I should create the files which you explained in the above answer.
My theme files are stored in following location 
app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme055
inside that one i18n directory is there but inside that only csv files are there.
Should i create inside that or should I create new directory as following
app/i18n/TemplateMonster/theme055

Please help about this. this is little urgent.

Thank You,
Kishan